# PHP ZipArchive failing to extract files on Ubuntu Linux running under Windows

Tags: php, linux, windows, ubuntu, zip

I'm getting the following warning

```
PHP Warning:  ZipArchive::extractTo(/mnt/c/some/folder\data.json):
failed to open stream: Invalid argument in /mnt/c/somefile.php on line 54
```

With this code, extracting any zip file using the Ubuntu subsystem on Windows running PHP 7.1:

```
<?php
class someClass
{
    public static function unzip($fn, $to = null)
    {
        $zip = new ZipArchive;

        if (is_null($to)) {
            $to = self::dirname($fn) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . self::filename($fn);
        }

        if (!is_dir($to)) {
            self::mkdir($to, 0755, true);
        }

        $res = $zip->open($fn);
        if ($res === true) {
            $zip->extractTo($to);
            $zip->close();
            return $to;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}

?>
```

The same code works fine on PHP 7.1 under Windows and PHP 7.1 under Linux (CentOS).

Comment: _Just a silly point:_ You set `$ds  = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;` and then never use `$ds` but you do use `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` ???

Comment: Oh yeah, in my original code I had a lot more stuff, I stripped out most of the irrelevant stuff but I must have left this in! Edited my answer and removed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the forward slash in the zip filename.

Using the following seemed to fix it:

```
<?php

class someClass
{
    public static function unzip($fn, $to = null)
    {
        $zip = new ZipArchive;
        $ds  = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
        if (is_null($to)) {
            $to = self::dirname($fn) . $ds . self::filename($fn);
        }

        $to = self::slashes($to);

        if (!is_dir($to)) {
            self::mkdir($to, 0755, true);
        }

        $res = $zip->open($fn);
        if ($res === true) {
            for ($i = 0; $i < $zip->numFiles; $i++) {
                $ifn = self::slashes($zip->getNameIndex($i));
                if (!is_dir(self::dirname($to . $ds . $ifn))) {
                    self::mkdir(self::dirname($to . $ds . $ifn), 0755, true);
                }

                $fp  = $zip->getStream($zip->getNameIndex($i));
                $ofp = fopen($to . $ds . $ifn, 'w');

                if (!$fp) {
                    throw new \Exception('Unable to extract the file.');
                }

                while (!feof($fp)) {
                    fwrite($ofp, fread($fp, 8192));
                }

                fclose($fp);
                fclose($ofp);
            }
            $zip->close();
            return $to;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static function slashes($fn)
    {
        return str_replace(['\\', '/'], DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $fn);
    }
?>
```